# после ввода слова в поле переадресация на сайт

Tags: javascript, jquery

как можно выполнить такую странную задачу:

допустим есть только поле ввода `<input type="text"/>`

после того как человек ввел бы ключевые слова "free registration"  его переносило на ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно именно найти `free registration` в поле, то данный способ подходит. Также я добавил событие `paste`, про которое все забывают, а ведь человек может вставить текст в форму копипастой:

```js
$('input').on('keyup paste', function(ev) {
 if(/free registration/.test(this.value)) {
  location.href = '...';
  console.log(this.value);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно следить за изменением текста в `<input>` с помощью обработчика события `change` и, в случае совпадения текста с необходимым, переходить на нужный URL с помощью изменения `window.location.href`:

```js
$(function() {
    $('input').on("change", function() {
        if (this.value == "free registration") {
            window.location.href = "http://google.ru";
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```